# Spacy - What does blank models contain?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, bert-language-model

Hy everyone,

I am trying to create a new NER model which labels custom entities.

As part of that I am using a new blank model for Italian with spacy.blank('it')

I'm creating a new NER pipeline with the labeled data to do the training, but I would like to  know what happens in the background.

If a blank model is used, how does the word embedding happen? I have read some where the core models use GloVe embedding but what happens when training a blank model?

In addition, if word embedding is happening through GloVe, can we use something like BERT to do that?

I'm just new to all this and finding hard to wrap my head around all that spacy offers.